# Fabric JS Select Only Few Objects Inside Group

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I want to select first two rows and 12 total objects in the group. is there any possibility to do with Fabric JS.
[Like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AaSv.png)

Comment: What do you want to do with them after selecting?

Comment: @shkaper change color only